# Normal map issue with subdivision surface

Tags: normals, subdivision-surface

My mesh uses a subsurf modifier, but when I apply a material with a normal map to the mesh, Cycles seems to be using the low-poly version's normals, rather than the smooth, subdivided version's normals.

Hopefully this illustrates my issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you show the node organisation?

Comment: @moonboots Added a screenshot.

Comment: perhaps someone could tell, if not you could share your file...

Comment: Turn on smooth shading.

Comment: @Leander Smooth shading is already on. I turned it off in the second screenshot to show the original geometry